# How to log all udp packets from port N in readable format?

Tags: logs, udp, trace, packet

How to log into file all udp packets (in and out) from port `N` in readable format (capture packet type (time stamp, name of error if one happens or message type, data size, data))?

Answer (score 1):

To capture traffic, use `tcpdump(1)` (it has a *very* extensive set of filtering options to define exactly what to capture, and can save the captured traffic to a file). To read the file, you can use the same `tcpdump` or the graphical `wireshark(1)`.